# PyQt issue with animating rotation

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qvariantanimation

I experiencing some issue while trying to understand how animate a qgraphicItem in Pyqt.

I'm trying to animate a qgraphicsItem inside a scene, but when the animation starts all the objects rotate. Is there someone who can help me?

here is my code.

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setRenderHints(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing
                            | QPainter.RenderHint.TextAntialiasing | QPainter.RenderHint.SmoothPixmapTransform)

        self.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView.ViewportUpdateMode.FullViewportUpdate)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(QRectF(-250, -250, 1000, 1000), self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.graphicItem = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.graphicItem.setZValue(10)
        self.graphicItem.setPos(100, 100)
        self.scene.addItem(self.graphicItem)
        self.scene.addRect(self.sceneRect(), brush=QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor.gray))

        self.animateRotation()

    def rot(self, angle: QVariant) -> None:
        self.rotate(self.graphicItem.rotation() - angle)
        self.graphicItem.setRotation(angle)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def animateRotation(self):
        self.animation = QVariantAnimation(self)
        self.animation.setStartValue(QVariant(0))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QVariant(180))
        self.animation.setDuration(10000)
        self.animation.start()
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.rot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = GraphicsView()
    w.resize(720, 720)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: what `self.rotate(self.graphicItem.rotation() - angle)` suppose to do?

Comment: Thank you vey much. Now it works!do you know how to change the pivot of an object for rotating it on it's own center?

Comment: `self.graphicItem.setTransformOriginPoint(QPointF(50,50))`

Comment: Thank you very much man!

I have a last question. How can i move and rotate the self.graphicItem?

Comment: @AlessioMichelassi Please take your time to carefully read and study the whole documentation about the [Graphics View framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) and QGraphicsItem.

Comment: @musicamante do you know how to do it? Maybe i tried and i not found a solution.